# Flutter:Has anyone use Iterable SDK with a flutter App for push notification

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app and need to integrate Iterable  SDK --https://support.iterable.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035018152  for Push Notification.

Has anyone completed this integration with Iterable/Futter  and did you encounter any issues. I have firebase push working in my app

Thanks for the information

Comment: Have you found anything?

Comment: nope.. still an open issue. I am hoping that they will have a flutter plugin to make this work